# Vue transition group not working in multi items carousel

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to animate multiple items at once like [this](http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?selectedKind=DayPicker&selectedStory=default&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel) which is a date picker but I am trying to achieve the animation like that using `transition-group` in Vue.js but it is not working. I created this snippet to demonstrate my problem https://codepen.io/nicholasnet/pen/ZMyvRd

Is there anyway to resolve this issue without generating any extra data than whats being rendered in VueJS?

Comment: _"like this"_ <- like what? That just looks like a date picker

Comment: Yes it is a date picker but I am looking to have transition like that for items that are displayed.